# index out of range exception when storing into asp.net session

Tags: asp.net, session, indexing

I'm building a web app that to build a report, but there are too many arguments to give each one a name, and I want to save them indexed by numbers so I can handle them with loops later on throughout the application.

However, I'm getting an index out of range on the very first session item(0)...as I understand it, I don't have to instantiate a session myself and this should work right?

```
        Session[0] = txtComplianceCaseID.Text;
        Session[1] = ddlState.SelectedValue;
        Session[2] = txtActingSupervisor.Text;
        Session[3] = ddlRiskTolerance.SelectedValue;
```

etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Session` object is a string dictionary; you should store objects in it with string keys.

Writing `Session[0]` will get or set the first item in session state.
Since Session state starts empty, it throws an exception.

Instead, you should use strings, like this:

```
Session["Compliance ID"] = txtComplianceCaseID.Text;
Session["State"] = ddlState.SelectedValue;
Session["Supervisor"] = txtActingSupervisor.Text;
Session["Risk Tolerance"] = ddlRiskTolerance.SelectedValue;
```

You can also call the [`Add` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.add.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Read more about Asp.net Session Object and how to fill it with information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287725%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: That's VS2003.  You should find a newer link.

Comment: Still works the same way. You can use the Add method and work with a "key", "value" pair...